Sum of residues $\sum_{s=1}^{n-1} r_s$

(Hacks, 1893) The number $n$ is prime if and only if
$$
\sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \sum_{b=1}^{n-1}\left\lfloor\frac{a b}{n}\right\rfloor=\frac{(n-1)^2(n-2)}{4}.
$$

The beginning of the proof goes like this:

Let $m$ and $n$ be any positive integers. Consider the following equations:
$$
\begin{gathered}
m = \left\lfloor \frac{m}{n} \right\rfloor n + r_1 \\
2m = \left\lfloor \frac{2m}{n} \right\rfloor n + r_2 \\
\vdots \\
(n-1)m = \left\lfloor \frac{(n-1)m}{n} \right\rfloor n + r_{n-1}
\end{gathered}
$$
where $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_{n-1}$ are the remainders when $m, 2m, \ldots, (n-1)m$ are divided by $n$. Adding these equations, we obtain
$$
   m\frac{n(n-1)}{2} = n \sum_{s=1}^{n-1} \left\lfloor \frac{sm}{n} \right\rfloor + \sum_{s=1}^{n-1} r_s.
$$
Let $m = m^\prime \operatorname{gcd}(m,n)$ and $n = n^\prime \operatorname{gcd}(m,n)$, where $m^\prime$ and $n^\prime$ are coprime. Then we get
$$
\sum_{s=1}^{n-1} r_s \color{red}{\overset{?}{=}} \operatorname{gcd}(m,n) \frac{n^\prime (n^\prime - 1)}{2} \operatorname{gcd}(m,n) = \frac{n(n - \operatorname{gcd}(m,n))}{2}.
$$

Now how on earth is this obtained in the last step? I do not get it. Sure, if $m$ and $n$ are already coprime, we get every residue $r_i$ one time. Since $mi \equiv mj \Rightarrow i \equiv j \pmod{n}$, the set $\{mi : i = 1, \ldots, n-1\}$ forms a complete residue system modulo $n$. Therefore, the sum of the remainders in this system must be equal to $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.
But if they are not coprime, then how do we get the sum of the residues like above?

Could you provide a source as to where you found all this?

For simpler algebra, let
$$d = \gcd(m, n), \;\; m = m^\prime d, \;\; n = n^\prime d, \;\; \gcd(m^\prime, n^\prime) = 1$$
We have for $0 \le s \le n - 1$ that
$$sm = \left\lfloor\frac{sm}{n}\right\rfloor n + r_s$$
Since $d \mid m$ and $d \mid n$, then $d \mid r_s$, i.e., $r_s = dq_s$ for some $0 \le q_s \le n^\prime - 1$. Thus, along with $\frac{m}{n} = \frac{m^\prime}{n^\prime}$, by dividing with $d$, the above equation becomes
$$sm^{\prime} = \left\lfloor\frac{sm^\prime}{n^\prime}\right\rfloor n^\prime + q_s$$
i.e., $q_s$ is the remainder when $sm^\prime$ are divided by $n^\prime$. As you've noted, since $\gcd(m^\prime, n^\prime) = 1$, then the values $\lbrace q_0, q_1, \ldots, q_{n^\prime - 1} \rbrace$ form a complete residue system modulo $n^\prime$. Thus, their sum is that of the integers $0$ to $n^\prime - 1$, inclusive, i.e., $\frac{n^\prime(n^\prime - 1)}{2}$. More generally, this is true for each subset of $n^{\prime}$ remainders, i.e., for $0 \le j \le d - 1$, we have
$$\sum_{t=0}^{n^\prime - 1}q_{jn^\prime + t} = \frac{n^\prime(n^\prime - 1)}{2}$$
Splitting the sum of $q_s$ terms below from $0$ to $n -1$ into $d$ groups of $n^\prime$ each, i.e., with indices going from $0$ to $n^\prime - 1$ (i.e., $0, 1, \ldots, n^\prime - 1$), $n^\prime$ to $2n^\prime-1$, etc., until $(d - 1)n^\prime$ to $dn^\prime - 1$, we get the terms having indices of $jn^\prime + t$, with $j$ going from $0$ to $d-1$, inclusive, and $t$ going from $0$ to $n^\prime - 1$, inclusive. Using this, and the above result, we then get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{s=1}^{n-1}r_s & = d\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}q_s \\
& = d\sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\left(\sum_{t=0}^{n^\prime - 1}q_{jn^\prime + t}\right) \\
& = \gcd(m,n)\sum_{j=0}^{\gcd(m,n)-1}\left(\frac{n^\prime(n^\prime - 1)}{2}\right) \\
& = \gcd(m,n)\frac{n^\prime(n^\prime-1)}{2}\gcd(m,n)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Alternatively, to use the equation summations in your question, then as shown in Summation of Floor Function series, we have
$$\sum_{t=0}^{n^\prime - 1}\left\lfloor\frac{tm^\prime}{n^\prime}\right\rfloor = \frac{(m^\prime - 1)(n^\prime - 1)}{2}$$
Using the above and the substitution $s = jn^\prime + t$, we get that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{s=1}^{n-1}\left\lfloor\frac{sm}{n}\right\rfloor & = \sum_{s=0}^{n-1}\left\lfloor\frac{sm^\prime}{n^\prime}\right\rfloor \\
& = \sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\left(\sum_{s=jn^\prime}^{(j+1)n^\prime-1}\left\lfloor\frac{sm^\prime}{n^\prime}\right\rfloor\right) \\
& = \sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\left(\sum_{t=0}^{n^\prime-1}\left\lfloor\frac{(jn^\prime+t)m^\prime}{n'}\right\rfloor\right) \\
& = \sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\left(\sum_{t=0}^{n'-1}\left(jm^\prime + \left\lfloor\frac{tm^\prime}{n^\prime}\right\rfloor\right)\right) \\
& = \sum_{j=0}^{d-1}n^\prime(jm^\prime) + \sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\left(\sum_{t=0}^{n'-1}\left\lfloor\frac{tm^\prime}{n^\prime}\right\rfloor\right) \\
& = \frac{m^\prime n^\prime(d-1)d}{2} + \frac{d(m^\prime - 1)(n^\prime - 1)}{2} \\
& = \frac{d}{2}((m^\prime n^\prime d - m^\prime n^\prime) + (m^\prime n^\prime - m^\prime - n^\prime + 1)) \\
& = \frac{d}{2}(m'n'd - m' - n' + 1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Finally, there's
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\sum_{s=1}^{n-1}r_s & = m\frac{n(n-1)}{2} - n\sum_{s=1}^{n-1}\left\lfloor \frac{sm}{n}\right\rfloor \\
& = \frac{n}{2}(m^\prime d(n-1) - d(m^\prime(n^\prime d) - m^\prime - n^\prime + 1)) \\
& = \frac{dn^\prime}{2}(m^\prime n - m^\prime - (m^\prime n - m^\prime - n^\prime + 1))d \\
& = \frac{dn^\prime}{2}(n^\prime - 1)d \\
& = \gcd(m,n)\frac{n^\prime(n^\prime-1)}{2}\gcd(m,n)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Sorry, can you elaborate on $$d\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}q_s=d\sum_{j=0}^{d-1}\left(\sum_{t=0}^{n^\prime - 1}q_{jn^\prime + t}\right)$$

The substitution is clear to me, I am trying to understand how you rewrote the sum from $0$ to $n-1$ of the $q_s$.

@Lonaldin Sorry, I misread what you wrote. Note that $n=dn^\prime$. I split the summation on the LHS into $d$ subgroups of $n^\prime$ terms each. Thus, there's the index going from $0$ to $n^\prime-1$ (i.e., $0$, $1$, etc., until $n^\prime-1$), then $2n^\prime$ to $3n^\prime-1$, etc., until $(d-1)n^\prime$ to $dn^\prime-1$. I next have $j$ represent the starting coefficient of $n^\prime$ for each group, so it goes from $0$ to $d-1$, inclusive. Also, $t$ represents the offset from the starting point, so each index is of the form $jn^\prime+t$ (i.e., the terms are $q_{jn^\prime+t}$), with ...

@Lonaldin (cont.) $t$ going from $0$ to $n^\prime-1$, inclusive. This, then, is a double summation, i.e., we get $d\sum_{s=0}^{n-1}q_s=d\sum_{j=0}^{d-1}(\sum_{t=0}^{n^\prime-1}q_{jn^\prime + t})$ that you asked about. I perhaps should have provided more detail there but, with the answer already being so relatively long as I provided $2$ different methods, I wasn't sure if it was required. Nonetheless, I may do that now, especially since it wasn't clear to you, it might not be to others as well.


Claim: $$n \text{ prime} \iff S’ := \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \sum_{b=1}^{n-1} ab \bmod n = \frac{n(n-1)^2}{2} $$

Proof: $\implies$
$$S’= \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \sum_{b=1}^{n-1} ab \bmod n \overset{(1.1)}{=} \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \sum_{b=1}^{n-1} b = \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)^2}{2}$$
$\impliedby$
Suppose $n$ is not prime and it is given that $S’ = \frac{n(n-1)^2}{2}$. But then $\exists f > 1$ s.t. $f \mid n$. Then $n=f\cdot k$ for $k<n$. Thus $$\sum_{b=1}^{n-1} fb \bmod n = \sum_{b=1}^{k-1} f^2 b = \frac{f^2(k-1)k}2 = \frac{n(n-f)}{2}<\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$
Thus $S’ < \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)^2}2$; a contradiction.

$$\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \sum_{b=1}^{n-1} \frac{ab}{n} - \left\{\frac{ab}{n}\right\} \tag{1.2}\\
&= \frac1{n} \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} a\sum_{b=1}^{n-1} b -  \frac1{n} \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \sum_{b=1}^{n-1} ab \bmod n \tag{1.3}\\
&= \frac1{n}\left(\sum_{a=1}^{n-1} a\right)^2 - \frac1{n} \sum_{a=1}^{n-1} \sum_{b=1}^{n-1} ab \bmod n \\
\end{align}$$
Thus $$n \text{ prime} \iff S = \frac{n(n-1)^2}{4} - \frac{(n-1)^2}{2} = \frac{(n-2)(n-1)^2}{4}$$
Explanations:
$(1.1)$: for any integer $a$ such that $\gcd(a,n)=1$, the set $\{ab \bmod n \ | \ 1\le b \le n-1 \land b \in \mathbb Z\}$ a complete residue system $\bmod n$ excluding the residue $0$. Thus this set contains the integers $\{1,2,3,\dots, n-1\}$.
$(1.2)$: $\lfloor x\rfloor = x - \{x\}$ where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$.
$(1.3)$: Since $a= kb+k’$ for some unique pair $(k,k’)$ where $0\le k’< b$ is guaranteed by Euclid’s division lemma we can write  $\left\{\frac{a}{b}\right\} = \left\{\frac{kb + k’}{b}\right\} = \left\{\frac{k’}{b}\right\} = \frac{k’}{b}$ and by definition $k’ = a \bmod b$
